# Flask extract value from drop down menu if value is url_for()

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, iframe

I want to be able to serve a static html file (located in `static/{platform}/graph.html`) within an `iframe` based on the value (`{platform}`) selected from a drop down menu. I also want to use the value selected in drop down menu in other places as well.

Right now I have something that works for serving static html file in the iframe and updating it based on drop down menu value, but the problem is that I'm unable to use the value from the drop down menu elsewhere.

I think it's because the value is a `url_for()`, but I'm not sure.

#### views.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/maps', methods=['GET','POST'])
def maps():
    print(request.form.get('location')) ## This prints None
    return render_template('maps.html')

@app.route('/static/<string:platform>/graph.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_plot(platform):
    print(request.form.get('location')) ## This prints None
    try:
        return send_file('static/{platform}/graph.html'.format(platform=platform))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error")
```

#### maps.html

```
<head>
    <!-- define iframe src based on drop down menu value -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setIframeSource() {
            var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
            var theIframe = document.getElementById('plot');
            var theUrl;

            theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            theIframe.src = theUrl;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- drop down menu -->
    <form id="select-platform" method="post">
       <label> Select Platform</label>
        <select name="location" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
          <option value="{{ url_for('show_plot', platform='web') }}">Web</option>
          <option value="{{ url_for('show_plot', platform='app') }}">App</option>
       </select>
    </form>
    <!-- embed static html file based on drop down menu value -->
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe
            id="plot"
            onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'
            style="border:0"
            src="{{ url_for('show_plot', platform='web') }}"
        >
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: By value you mean `'web'` or `'app'`? You're not wanting to use the URL generated by `url_for`? If that's the case, store the value in a `data-attribute` for each option.

Comment: So I'm not seeing a URL when trying to extract value from drop down menu. See commented code in `maps()` and `show_plots()` methods. Is my code to get the drop menu value the issue then?

Comment: I would also be fine with changing my drop down menu to have `web`/`app` as values, but then I have a different problem is figuring out how to change the `setIframeSource()` function to utilize those values and generate `url_for()`

Comment: How are you sending/posting your form to the `maps()` or `show_plots()` endpoints?

Comment: I guess i'm not? Right now it's setup purely to embed a static html file in an iframe and also update src of iframe by changing drop down menu selection without refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `submit` button that made a `POST` request to a new `_refresh_plot` endpoint allowed me to see the URL from the `url_for()` value from drop down menu value

### views.py

```
@app.route('/_refresh_plot', methods=['POST'])
def _refresh_plot():
    pattern = '\/static\/([\w]+)\/graph\.html'
    url = request.form.get('location')
    platform = re.search(pattern, url)[1]
    print(platform)
```

### maps.html

```
<form id="select-platform" method="post" action="{{ url_for('_refresh_plot') }}>
  <label> Select Platform</label>
  <select name="location" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
    <option value="{{ url_for('show_plot', platform='web') }}">Web</option>
    <option value="{{ url_for('show_plot', platform='app') }}">App</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Refresh</button> 
</form>
```